# How to sort Javascript array of object on the basis of one value out of many values

Tags: javascript

I have an array like following:

```
const arr = [{name:"apple", qtySold: 30, revenue: 90}, {name:"pie", qtySold: 10, revenue: 100}, {name:"beer", qtySold: 25, revenue: 95}]
```

How can I sort this group on the basis of revenue in DESC order? So I want the result to be:

```
const sortedArr = [{name:"pie", qtySold: 10, revenue: 100}, {name:"beer", qtySold: 25, revenue: 95},{name:"apple", qtySold: 30, revenue: 90}]
```

I found solutions for object with just one value, but what can I do in this case?

Comment: *I found solutions for object with just one value* - the solution to sort an array of objects is the same regardless of if the object has 1 property or 1000.

Comment: I found a common solution to be :

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});

but how does it know to sort from qtySold or revenue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sort()` method like that.

```js
const arr = [{name:"apple", qtySold: 30, revenue: 90}, {name:"pie", qtySold: 10, revenue: 100}, {name:"beer", qtySold: 25, revenue: 95}]

arr.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj2.revenue - obj1.revenue);

console.log(arr)
```